# What kind of mathematical approach can you use to find all non-repeated combinations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

At first glance I thought this was a non-repeated combination or permutation, but those use a set length. So, I guessed this might be a partition of a positive integer, but it's not looking like that. I'm not that familiar in the area of mathematics so I'm not sure what math was used to derive all these non-repeated sets.

Example Input:

Set 1: 13, 15, 12, 16, 17

Set 2: 16, 13, 12, 18, 9

Set 3: 12, 9, 17, 4, 5

Example Output:

Intersection 1 & 2: 12, 13,16

Intersection 2 & 3: 12, 9

Intersection 1 & 3: 12, 17

Intersection 1, 2 & 3: 12

Comment: It looks like a regular old intersection: $A \cap B = \{x: x \in A\ \mathrm{ and }\ x \in B\}$, from set theory. Since it's looking at all (non-trivial) intersections, it could have something to do with Inclusion-Exclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no way of knowing which elements belong to which sets, then building up the intersections incrementally (increasing the number of sets in each intersection at each iteration) is basically the only way to go. If the number of sets is pretty small compared to the number of elements in the sets and the intersections, then you can speed up the calculation by finding the partition of an intersection into an intersection of two intersections of fewer number of sets, such that the two intersection sets you are intersecting are as small as possible. Also you can use hash tables to quickly compute the intersections, there is a lot of accessible literature on hash tables if you're unfamiliar.